# Scrapy на нескольких уровнях

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy

Есть сайт с новостями на главной. Хочу получить список новостей и их авторов. Но авторы указаны только на страницах самих новостей. Для этого мне придётся объединять результаты, но как это сделать с Scrapy? Я нуб в этом. Не видел пока ни одного варианта чтобы можно было получить результат, а не вернуть его в Scrapy.

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на страницу.

Comment: Для примера может подойти этот сайт, а в качестве данных со страницы - ник того кто дал отмеченный ответ. Мне надо только узнать как пройтись по странице и получить результаты внутри spider, а не возвращать их сразу в scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

[Советую почитать документацию](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html?highlight=pipeline#)
pipeline.py - в этом файле описывается куда и как сохранять [Items](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html). 
Если по простому - то всю информацию представляете в виде Items, а в pipelines описываете как и куда сохранять items.

Comment: Трудность в том что у меня Item собирается с двух страниц на разных уровнях. Я конечно ещё посмотрю доки, но что-то желания нет, да и уполз уже на более привычные либы.

Comment: Это уже больше вопрос к структуре организации вашего проекта. Что мешает обойти все новости по порядку, одним пауком? Заходим на страницу, парсим новость, заголовок, автора. Item и будет содержать эти поля. Или я вас не правильно понял?

Comment: На главной есть информация о новости, которой нет на странице новости. Да, обычно данные на странице новости это надмножество, но в некоторых случаях это не так, потому и задал вопрос.